# Having problems adding new content to a xml file with dataset in C#/.NET

Tags: c#, .net, xml, datatable, dataset

I am trying to store info in a XML using C# and .Net, but only the last info I write and "submit" to the XML using a buttonclick event. What I have entered previously is overwritten.

This is the code :

```
private void lagre_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn("Fullt navn");
        DataColumn dc2 = new DataColumn("Start dato");
        DataColumn dc3 = new DataColumn("Antall dager");

        dt.Columns.Add(dc1);
        dt.Columns.Add(dc2);
        dt.Columns.Add(dc3);

        dt.Rows.Add(gjestenavnInput.Text, datoInnsjekk.Text, antallDager.Text);

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);
        ds.WriteXml("gjesteInfo.xml");


        gjesterutenrom.Items.Add(gjestenavnInput.Text);

        gjestenavnInput.Text = "";
        datoInnsjekk.Text = "";
        antallDager.Text = "";


    }
```

I tried to put the construction of the DataTable, DataColumn and Dataset outside the button event, but then it would not store any data in the XML. Maybe there is a problem with dt.rows.add etc., but I dont know how else to write it. Any ideas?

---

Thanks for you effort so far, RyanWH. :) I have now tried to play around with your suggestions, maybe I misunderstood something but this is what I did :

```
private void InitDataTable()
    {
        dt = new DataTable();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXml("gjesteInfo.xml");
        dt = ds.Tables[0];


        if (dt.Columns == null){
       DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn("Fullt navn");
       DataColumn dc2 = new DataColumn("Start dato");
       DataColumn dc3 = new DataColumn("Antall dager");

        dt.Columns.Add(dc1);
        dt.Columns.Add(dc2);
        dt.Columns.Add(dc3);
        }

        ds.WriteXml("gjesteInfo.xml");

    }



    private void lagre_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        InitDataTable();

        dt.Rows.Add(gjestenavnInput.Text, datoInnsjekk.Text, antallDager.Text);

        gjesterutenrom.Items.Add(gjestenavnInput.Text);

        gjestenavnInput.Text = "";
        datoInnsjekk.Text = "";
        antallDager.Text = "";


    }
```

This produce the same outcome. It overwrites the old content in the XML file.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it using Merging suggested by David S.

Here is what I did :

```
    DataTable dt;

    private void InitDataTable()
    {
        dt = new DataTable();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXml("gjesteInfo.xml");
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);

        DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn("Fullt navn");
        DataColumn dc2 = new DataColumn("Start dato");
        DataColumn dc3 = new DataColumn("Antall dager");

        dt.Columns.Add(dc1);
        dt.Columns.Add(dc2);
        dt.Columns.Add(dc3);

        dt.Rows.Add(gjestenavnInput.Text, datoInnsjekk.Text, antallDager.Text);

        ds.Merge(dt); //Merging the dataset with the table and preventing it to be overwritten

        ds.WriteXml("gjesteInfo.xml");

    }



    private void lagre_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        InitDataTable();

        dt.Rows.Add(gjestenavnInput.Text, datoInnsjekk.Text, antallDager.Text);

        gjesterutenrom.Items.Add(gjestenavnInput.Text);

        gjestenavnInput.Text = "";
        datoInnsjekk.Text = "";
        antallDager.Text = "";


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to append information to your DataTable when you press the button?  The first line, the declaration of your table, should be defined for your entire class, probably where your 'gjestenavnInput' variable is declared.

```
    DataTable dt;
```

This will allow your button function to refer to this data table, and it also allows the table to be persistent while your program runs.

Then, you'll want these lines in your constructor/initialization to create your table and set up your columns:

```
    dt = new DataTable();

    DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn("Fullt navn");
    DataColumn dc2 = new DataColumn("Start dato");
    DataColumn dc3 = new DataColumn("Antall dager");

    dt.Columns.Add(dc1);
    dt.Columns.Add(dc2);
    dt.Columns.Add(dc3);
```

Your code, as it is right now, is making a brand new DataTable with 0 columns and 0 rows every time you click the button.  Then, you create and add three columns to the table.  Finally, you add one row to the table.  After all of your table manipulations, you write the table to XML, and at this point all your table knows are these things: It has 3 columns, and it has 1 row. Then, you reset the fields to empty strings.

At the end of the function, your DataTable object goes out of scope and gets deleted, which means that the next time your button is clicked the exact same thing happens: A table with 0 columns and 0 rows is created, three columns are added, one row is added, it is written to XML, and you reset your fields to empty strings.

**Second Edit**

I modified some of your updated code below.  Hope this helps.

```
private void InitDataTable()
{
    dt = new DataTable();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds.ReadXml("gjesteInfo.xml");

    DataTableCollection tables = ds.Tables;

    if (0 == tables.Count){
        DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn("Fullt navn");
        DataColumn dc2 = new DataColumn("Start dato");
        DataColumn dc3 = new DataColumn("Antall dager");

        dt.Columns.Add(dc1);
        dt.Columns.Add(dc2);
        dt.Columns.Add(dc3);
    }
    else 
    {
        dt = tables[0];
    }
}

private void lagre_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    InitDataTable();

    dt.Rows.Add(gjestenavnInput.Text, datoInnsjekk.Text, antallDager.Text);

    gjesterutenrom.Items.Add(gjestenavnInput.Text);

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds.Tables.Add(dt);
    ds.WriteXml("gjesteInfo.xml");

    gjestenavnInput.Text = "";
    datoInnsjekk.Text = "";
    antallDager.Text = "";


}
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct. How should I construct the table without it beeing overwritten every time the software is used?

Comment: I edited my answer.  What you'll want to do is read in your previously saved table when your program starts up.  Be careful of the cases where the file doesn't exist or it's empty.  For example, if there's no data table to load from the XML, then you need to set up the columns of dt.  If the table already exists, you don't need to add more columns(it should already have the three columns you want).

Comment: Thanks for you effort so far, RyanWH. Check out my own answer to this question, with the use of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, `ds.WriteXml("gjesteInfo.xml");` overwrites everything in the file. You need to load the file, and merge it with your new info. Maybe `DataSet`s `Merge` function would be useful here.

edit: look here to see which functions would suit you  to solve the problem of loading->merging->saving http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/831szy8a.aspx

Comment: So if I am to change the WriteXML and use Merge function instead, where I am to create the XML?

Answer (score 0):

You need to *read* the existing data first, add to it, then *write* it. Briefly:

```
dt.ReadXml();
dt.AddRow(...);
dt.WriteXml();
```

XML files are just text files. You can't write into the middle of them.